Company wants to revert my working hours to previous arrangement
I had a contract as a home shopping driver, and I worked Sunday evenings until 10pm, and Monday through Thursday from 7am until 2pm. However, for a few months, I started working Sunday mornings instead, which the previous department manager accepted. Now that he's gone, they want me to revert back to the original contract. Because of childcare issues, this change is difficult for me. However, they are insisting on it. Can they do this?

which the previous department manager accepted - verbally? in writing?

Usually, verbal commitments are understanding between people. written commitments are legally bound.

@SouravGhosh In Australia, verbal commits are just as valid.

Your title says everything right? "Not worked my contracted day for months but they now want to go back to that day in contract"  So what I understand from the title is that for some months your manager allowed that you work different days than the ones specified in your contract and now that he's gone your new managers want you to stick to what your contract says. Is this assumption correct? Because if it's correct you already have the answer in the title.


Can they do this?

Generally speaking, if you have a written contract then they can ask to to fulfil it. Normally, legally binding changes to a written contract should be in writing as well.
If you have the changes in your contract in writing, then you have valid contract and they "cannot" do that. I put "cannot" in quotes becaue I don't know your contract and labor laws in your location or how hard it would be for them to just terminate it alltogether.
If your old manager allowed this exception, it is fully within your new managers right to not allow it and ask you to work as your contract says you would.
In some juristictions there is something called Customary law, where basically if all parties do something long enough without complaining, it becomes the new norm, even if not explicitely written down. At least in Germany, we are talking about two years here, so a few months will probably not be enough, even if something like that exists in your juristiction.
